# How to retrieve the data from SQL with $stateParams in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to bring the data from SQL with $stateParam. However, I realized that the code I wrote brings the sequence number of Array.

[in AngularJS]

```
$http.get('../crud/read.php').then(function(response){
    $scope.members = response.data;
    $scope.member_data = $scope.members[$stateParams.id];
});
```

This bring the number of ARRAY ID.

What I would like to bring is the data from TABLE A in SQL.

Let say if the TABLE A is 'member_id'. How can I bring the TABLE A using $stateParams?

Any advice would be really highly appreciated!!

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Post `$stateParams.id` to server and use it in query to return what you want not all data

Comment: Thank you. Hope this helps the others as well.